# Change appearance of WPF DatePicker's textbox

Tags: wpf, datepicker, controltemplate

Changing the Foreground property of the WPF DatePicker does change the colour of the text in the text box, but changing the Background property doesn't. But you can change it by styling the contained DatePickerTextBox.  So I ended up with this:

```
<DatePicker Foreground="Yellow" >
    <DatePicker.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}" >
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.Resources>
</DatePicker>
```

Is there a tidier way of doing this without templating the whole control? 
Is there a way to just template the named part i.e. PART_TextBox?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a tidier way of doing this without templating the whole control? Is there a way to just template the named part i.e. PART_TextBox?

No. You can't set any properties of an element that is defined inside a control's template (and that is not bound to any properties of the "parent" control itself) without re-defining the entire template or use implicit styles.

Answer (score 0):

This is also an issue with Combo Boxes.  You can add a trigger to fix this as shown.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="TextBlockStyle">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DatePicker}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```